# How to use sched run at given time and number of times?

Tags: python, scheduler, execute

How can I use sched to run function `test()`at user given time `i` and `runtime`? I am not sure the what parameter should put it in `sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)`.
It is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

i = str(raw_input('What date to start function: '))
runtime = raw_input('How many times to run: ')
try:
    dt_start = datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
except ValueError:
    print "Incorrect format"


def test():
    print "Hello World"
```

Comment: The [Python Module of the Week](https://pymotw.com/2/sched/index.html#module-sched) website has examples of using the `shed` module. There's also a Python 3 [version](https://pymotw.com/3/sched/index.html).

Comment: Is that the code like this? s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep) s.enter(runtime, 1, test, ())